# Why doesn't native css smooth scroll work in this example?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply `scroll-behaviour:smooth` css property to the body of a web page, but it still behaves with instant scroll.

This w3schools example works fine for me: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_scroll_behavior

But my jsfiddle doesn't: https://jsfiddle.net/cs4b2nr0/1/

I can't figure out what's wrong with my markup/styles.

Comment: Thanks for the rectified English syntax, itsanantk. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the example from W3school, you should add this CSS property to your HTML and not the body, bit for sade side you can apply on both, check this now.

```css
body,html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<p id="a">a- <a href="#a">a</a> <a href="#b">b</a> <a href="#c">c</a> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipitLorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipitLorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipitLorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipitLorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipitLorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipitLorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipitLorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit.</p>

<p id="b">b - <a href="#a">a</a> <a href="#b">b</a> <a href="#c">c</a> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit.</p>

<p id="c">c - <a href="#a">a</a> <a href="#b">b</a> <a href="#c">c</a> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita enim praesentium, veniam fuga cumque maxime architecto delectus doloremque doloribus placeat vel voluptates, explicabo, veritatis deleniti impedit rerum harum minus suscipit.</p>
```

Comment: and if this answer helps you, dont forget to upvote and mark it as right answer